# SQL SSRS Reportbuilder 3.0 2012 Last day of the month before the previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I need to get the last day of the month before the previous month, in this case meaning the 31st of January. I tried the following expression `=dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))` but it will return the 29th of January (because February had only 29 days I think). How I can I make sure the 31st of January shows up? Thanks guys.

Comment: You also tagged sqlserver. You can use this syntax in sqlserver 2012: SELECT EOMonth(DATEADD(month, -2, getdate()))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of trial and error I finally got the right answer in Report Builder. I used the following expression: `=DateSerial(Year(Today()),Month(DateAdd("m", -1, Today())),0)`